# Spring Database Lock: Need help in understanding the condition for database deadlock

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, pessimistic-locking

I am using Spring-Data-Jpa and using @Lock annotation(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) for taking database(Oracle) locks. I need help in understanding that whether the following scenario can lead to a database dead lock.

1. Transaction 1(PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW, ISOLATION_DEFAULT) one takes a database lock over say Teacher table(say lock is taken over row with id=1). It tries to insert a new record in the child table say Meeting. No update is done on the Teacher table
2. While Transaction 1 is in progress. Transaction 2(PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_DEFAULT) tries to update the Teacher table(row with id=1). It does not take a database lock.
3. Since the lock is taken over row with id 1. Transaction 2 has to wait for transaction 1 to get over.

Can this condition lead to a database dead lock?

Comment: which transaction propagation do you use?

Comment: Transaction 1(PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW, ISOLATION_DEFAULT).Transaction 2(PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_DEFAULT)

Comment: With oracle the default isolation is READ COMMITTED.

Answer (score 0):

I think your case will lead to a database lock, yes, but no deadlock will be triggered. And database lock is something we expect to happen to achieve ACID transaction.